# "Server failed to resume the transaction" - Best practices using LINQ to Classes

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Using SQLSERVER 2008R2, VisualStudio 2010, .NET 4.0

I'm getting this periodic exception: "Server failed to resume the transaction - Desc 2000003" (number changes)

Reading online forums and here, I found the main cause is to properly instance and close the Connections.

What should my classes look like?

Create the DataContext on Class level and use it on all methods?

```
public class BusProcess
{

    RENDBDataContext db = new RENDBDataContext();

    public void Insert()
    {
        //Do stuff here...
        db.InsertProcedure(...);
    }
 }
```

Create and dispose a new DataContext on each method through using() ?

```
public class BusProcess
{

    public void Insert()
    {
        using(RENDBDataContext db = new RENDBDataContext())
        {
            //Do stuff here...
            int sample = db.SomeObject.SingleOrDefault(...).Id;
            db.InsertProcedure(...);
        }
    }
 }
```

Or maybe a different approach (Best practice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, the lifetime of a `DataContext` instance should be bound to a single unit of work -- which is exemplified by your second usage.

The first usage can also be fine, depending on how long-lived the enclosing class is -- but whatever the case there, ensure that class implements `IDisposable`, dispose of the enclosed `DataContext` in your implementation of `Dispose()`, and wrap usages of *that* class with `using()`.

Comment: If I use the SECOND example and, let's say, the method returns an IQueryable<>, then I won't be able to use that data, cause the DataContext is already disposed? And: for disposing the DataContext is it enough to just set it's variable to null?

Comment: @Vitor: You're right that a returned `IQueryable` will fail, but you can materialize the query (i.e. call `ToList` or `ToArray`) and return that instead. Simply setting the variable to null is not adequate for classes that implement `IDisposable`: the point of that interface is to call `Dispose()` (via `using`, for example) as soon as you're finished with the instance. Otherwise, its resources won't be cleaned up until the GC collects the object (and calls its finalizer).

Answer (score 1):

Second approach is better than having DataContext around all time. It will prevent memory consumption when calling Load etc. Also remember that connections are pooled, so creating new DataContext is not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of both.  Use the first method but have your classes implement `IDisposable` and call dispose on the context in your classes dispose method.  You then use your classes in using statements.  You could also pass in a `DataContext` in a constructor of your class for added flexibility.